# QStandardItemModel -- delete a row

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

I am using `QStandardItemModel` inside `QTableView`. Here I have two button & `QTableView` inside my mainwindow. Rows will vary inside the model.
Two Buttons are there to add/delete a row (test case).

Adding row to the model is working, slot for the `ADD button` :--

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    model->insertRow(model->rowCount());
}
```

But my program is crashing when I am deleting a row from the model, slot for the `Delete button` :--

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QModelIndexList indexes = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selection().indexes();
    QModelIndex index = indexes.at(0);
    model->removeRows(index.row(),1);

}
```

Please suggest what I have to change in my code to make delete working.

Edit :----

Got it working.

```
QModelIndex currentIndex = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
model->removeRow(currentIndex.row());
```

Comment: What does `indexes.size()` shows?

Comment: @Amartel application is crashing

Comment: please suggest how to get it working ?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is - you are trying to delete row without selection. Try this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QModelIndexList indexes = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
    while (!indexes.isEmpty())
    {
        model->removeRows(indexes.last().row(), 1);
        indexes.removeLast();
    }
}
```